# Encoding Mess - ASP.net,WCF,Linq-SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq, wcf

I have been pushing to finish off this project since 1 week and have been stuck with one problem that god knows how I missed. We have a sql server database that has 2 tables (of concern here).

```
Table 1 (id,langCode,englishText,translatedTextInUnicode{nvarchar(MAX)})
Table 2 (id,langCode,englishText,translatedTextInUtf-8{nvarchar(MAX)})
```

Application is layered app like db -> linq-sql ->wcf -> ASP.net 3.5

I have tried many things like using `<meta>` tag, using `<globalization>` tag in `web.config` but to no avail. Really struggling to show utf-characters in general and both when used with an accordion control on aspx pages. All I get is garbage text.

Need some help!

Answer (score 4):

Besides the usual link to Joel's seminal article about [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), I can only strongly recommend to **use the same encoding throughout the whole database**.